# How to properly replace jquery mobile pages in the DOM

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am using jquery mobile and custom i18n functionality. When the user changes the language from the settings I want to remove the existing pages and put them again into the DOM (I am using Handlebars.js so the new pages will be shown in the new language).

What is the proper way to accomplish this? Simply removing the pages with .remove() and then appending them to the DOM is definitely not the way to go - the history gets broken, the pages don't get enhanced and I'm not even sure if it is possible to change the current page this way.

Is this even possible or should I consider refactoring my i18n so it doesn't require refreshing the whole DOM?

Comment: Do you have your pages all as separate files? Or a bunch on jQuery Mobile Pages in one html file?

Comment: They are all in separate files by I'm loading them in advance and keep them in a JS object so I can inject them faster into the DOM.